A-Frame clickable models
I have a mobile AR web page using A-Frame and I would like to make some of the models in the scene clickable.
Using this code the console logs when the models become visible, but not when they are clicked on by the user.
<script type="text/javascript">
    AFRAME.registerComponent('clickhandler', {
        schema: {
            txt: { default: 'default' }
        },
        init: function () {
            var data = this.data;
            var el = this.el;
            el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                console.log(data.txt, el, e)
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<a-scene embedded arjs="debugUIEnabled: false;" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" id="mainScene" embedded arjs
    renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true">

    <!-- —————————————————————————————————————————————————————┤ CHANGE THE GLIFF FILE NAME HERE -> -->
    <a-marker type="pattern" url="pattern-marker.patt" emitevents="true" smooth="true" , smoothTolerance="0.02"
        smoothCount="5" smoothThreshold="2">

        <!-- —————————————————————STATIC MODELS -> -->
        <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" rotation="-110 0 180" gltf-model="Models/house.glb"
            animation-mixer></a-entity>
        <!-- —————————————————————CLICKABLE MODELS -> -->
        <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" clickhandler="txt:hob" rotation="-110 0 180"
            gltf-model="Models/hob.glb" animation-mixer cursor='rayOrigin: mouse'></a-entity>
        <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" clickhandler="txt:sign" rotation="-110 0 180"
            gltf-model="Models/sign.glb" animation-mixer cursor='rayOrigin: mouse'></a-entity>
        <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" clickhandler="txt:boiler" rotation="-110 0 180"
            gltf-model="Models/boiler.glb" animation-mixer cursor='rayOrigin: mouse'></a-entity>
        <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" clickhandler="txt:window" rotation="-110 0 180"
            gltf-model="Models/window.glb" animation-mixer cursor='rayOrigin: mouse'></a-entity>
        <!--LIGHTS -->
        <a-entity light="type: ambient; intensity: 0.5;"></a-entity>
        <a-entity light="type:directional; castShadow: true" position="10 10 60"></a-entity>

    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>

I can't see anything that would make the click trigger when the models become visible and I don't know why nothing happens when I click. Any ideas would be amazing! Thank you!!
